# Run flutter app from iphone launcher itself

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm new to flutter, I developed apps in Android Studio for ios devices, and they run perfectly when I run them from Android Studio onto the real device. However, if I try to run the app from the iphone itself (from the launcher icon), the app imediately closes and doesn't run.

Why would this be? Is there anything I can do in the code to enable the app to run from the phone itself, not just through running it in Android Studio?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you running the debug version? Are you using the simulator or an actual device? Ideally, if you want to use the app without depending on the devtools, you should run the release version (`flutter run --release`).

Comment: I run it in android studio with the green arrow. Is this debug version?

Comment: There are two buttons, both are used for debuging. But arrow button does not debug as a breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, by default android studio runs the app in debug mode (which is not the same thing as running a debugger). Try plugging your device and running `flutter run --release` on your terminal to launch the app in release mode.

Comment: This is my answer. Thanks!